# Dropzone js not working without form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

How can I use dropzone without using the class in the form.

I basically want to have a `div` inside a form and call `class="dropzone"` in that div. But it doesn't seems to work.

Here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css"/>
    <script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "file-upload"})
    </script>

    <body>
        <form action="upload.php">
            <input type="text">
            <div id="myId" class="dropzone"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your url parameter is not pointing to any valid php file. I believe your code should be thus

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css"/>
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "upload.php"}) //according to your forms action
</script>

<body>
    <form action="upload.php">
        <input type="text">
        <div id="myId" class="dropzone"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: "file-upload" is a perfect route for php to process. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing) is an example of an framework for php that map whatever routes to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Initiate `.ready` event when DOM ready and use like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css"/>
    <script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "file-upload"});
        });
    </script>

    <body>
        <form action="upload.php">
            <input type="text">
            <div id="myId" class="dropzone"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```