# Dropzone JS not working with out form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dropzone.js

I am new to dropzone.js and am having nightmares since long time to get the dropzone working on my asp.net web page. Basically I want to implement it with  instead of . I did all the research but most of the examples are used only with forms to upload images.

I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188751/dropzone-js-not-working-without-form) but that didn't work for me.

Its not at all displaying the drag and drop area to select images. Instead its always going with the fallback and displaying the normal file upload control. I am testing it on IE10. I have downloaded and referrenced all the required files on the webpage like its CSS and min.js file along with the other two images which should get displayed while page loads (but didn't).

Below is my code. One thing to note here is I am implementing it inside custom user control. Also this custom user control will get loaded inside an Ajax UpdatePanel control.
Here's the code:

```
References:
<script src="../Scripts/dropzone.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link href="../Styles/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Styles/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       Dropzone.options.dropzonediv = {
            url: '/HttpHanlders/Upload.ashx',
            init: function () {
                this.on("complete", function (data) {
                    var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
                });
            }
        };
    });
</script>

HTML:
<td style="width: 50%; border-right: 1px solid #F0F0F0">
     <div class="dropzone" id="dropzonediv">
          <div class="fallback">
              <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
              <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
          </div>
     </div>
</td>
```

I find dropzone feasible and best suited for my requirement that's why I don't want to go with any other file upload implementation. Please help!!!

Comment: And there are not error messages displaying. its simply displaying fallback. can somebody provide me working solution. It will be a great help!

Comment: I don't know if this is gonna help you, but there is a typo in the URL value (HttpHanlders).

Comment: no that's not the issue. problem is dropzone not even displaying on page.

Comment: Hey all thanks for response. logging in in after long time. but was able to find the solution deep diving line by line, adding and removing controls. I was not referencing the Drop zone script correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this script before calling any option

```
<script>
$("div#dropzonediv ").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
</script>
```